# Checkpoint data corruption in Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am testing checkpointing and write ahead logs with this basic Spark streaming code below. I am checkpointing into a local directory. After starting and stopping the application a few times (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>) - it would refuse to start, for what looks like some data corruption in the checkpoint directoty. I am getting:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 80.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 80.0 (TID 17, localhost): com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 13994
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:137)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:670)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:781)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoDeserializationStream.readObject(KryoSerializer.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$1.getNext(Serializer.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:192)
```

Full code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._

object ProtoDemo {
  def createContext(dirName: String) = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("mything")
    conf.set("spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable", "true")

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))
    ssc.checkpoint(dirName)
    val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("127.0.0.1", 9999)
    val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
    val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1))
    val wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(_ + _)
    val runningCounts = wordCounts.updateStateByKey[Int] {
      (values: Seq[Int], oldValue: Option[Int]) =>
        val s = values.sum
        Some(oldValue.fold(s)(_ + s))
      }

  // Print the first ten elements of each RDD generated in this DStream to the console
    runningCounts.print()
    ssc
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val hadoopConf = new Configuration()
    val dirName = "/tmp/chkp"
    val ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(dirName, () => createContext(dirName), hadoopConf)
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }

}
```

Comment: Try using reliable filesystem like hdfs and see whether there is any error.

Comment: Tried with S3, and it still happens. I believe the corruption happens in the write ahead log.

Comment: which version of spark you are using ? 1.6 or 2.0 ?

Comment: how are you running this ? stand alone mode ,YARN ,Mesos ,local ?

Comment: Spark 2.0. I can reproduce the problem in a standalone mode, and also when starting a local cluster from sbt. Example project: https://github.com/thesamet/spark-issue

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are trying to do is a driver failure scenario , for this to work , based on the cluster you are running you have to follow the below instructions to monitor the driver process and relaunch the driver if it fails

Configuring automatic restart of the application driver - To automatically recover from a driver failure, the deployment infrastructure that is used to run the streaming application must monitor the driver process and relaunch the driver if it fails. Different [cluster managers](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon) have different tools to achieve this.

1. Spark Standalone - A Spark application driver can be submitted to
   run within the Spark Standalone cluster (see [cluster deploy
   mode](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon)), that is, the application driver itself runs on one of the
   worker nodes. Furthermore, the Standalone cluster manager can be
   instructed to supervise the driver, and relaunch it if the driver
   fails either due to non-zero exit code, or due to failure of the
   node running the driver. See cluster mode and supervise in the Spark
   Standalone [guide](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon) for more details.
2. YARN - Yarn supports a similar mechanism for automatically restarting an application. Please refer to YARN documentation for
   more details.
3. Mesos - [Marathon](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon) has been used to achieve this with Mesos.

You need to configure write ahead logs as below ,there are special instructions for S3 which you need to follow.

While using S3 (or any file system that does not support flushing) for write ahead logs, please remember to enable

**spark.streaming.driver.writeAheadLog.closeFileAfterWrite
   spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.closeFileAfterWrite.**

See Spark [Streaming Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/configuration.html#spark-streaming) for more details.

Comment: The problem I describe happens when t manually restart after a failure. When I restart the 2nd or 3rd time, I'll get the exception mentioned in the question. Would automatic restart make any difference?

Comment: have you set these to true ? spark.streaming.driver.writeAheadLog.closeFileAfterWrite spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.closeFileAfterWrite.

Comment: Yes, when testing with S3 and still had this problem. Are they needed for a local file system?

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks rather Kryo Serializer issue than checkpoint corruption.
At code example (including GitHub project), Kryo Serialization is not configured.
Since it is not configured **KryoException** exception could not happen.

When using "write ahead logs", and restoring from a directory, all Spark config is getting from there. 
At your example, **createContext** method does not call when starting from the checkpoint.

I assume the issue is **another application** were tested before with the same checkpoint directory, where Kryo Serializer where configured.
And current application fails to be restored from that checkpoint.